# Get all journey ids via API/Query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

is there a way i can retrieve id's for all my existing journeys in the BU via API or Query.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can retrieve all journeys using the following REST API request:

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
GET /interaction/v1/interactions/
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Just iterate through the JSON response and snag the ID for each of your journeys.